# SQL STATEMENT WITH WHERE != TWICE

Tags: mysql, sql

When I run the SQL first sql statement I get results. When i run the Second statement I get no result.

STATEMENT1:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table.id = table2.id
WHERE file_id = '5871' AND table1.debit = 0 AND table1.credit = 0
```

STATEMENT2:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table.id = table2.id
WHERE file_id = '5871' AND table1.debit != 0 AND table1.credit != 0
```

I have tried running sql statement with only one `!=` and it works.

STATEMENT1:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table.id = table2.id
WHERE file_id = '5871' AND table1.debit = 0 AND table1.credit = 0
```

STATEMENT2:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table.id = table2.id
WHERE file_id = '5871' AND table1.debit != 0 AND table1.credit != 0
```

I expect all rows that have 0 debits and credits not to be displayed.
This is my db data WHERE file_id = '5871'
[My database where file id = 5871](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXHAx.jpg)

Comment: Do you have any records where both `debit` and `credit` are non-zero values at the same time, or is this an either-or situation? I'm assuming you may have meant (logically) `(table1.debit != 0 OR table1.credit !=0)`. Some sample data and desired results would help us understand better though.

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, no images.

Comment: Show us the result from `SELECT ... WHERE file_id = '5871'`.

Comment: Yes in my records exists rows with 0 credit and 0 debits. Also there are rows with debit >0 and credit >0

Comment: Please [edit] and include that sample data! Without it, we'd just be guessing, and that's a waste of everyone's time.

Comment: I have updated and included screenshot of DB where file_id = '5871'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want `or`:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 INNER JOIN 
     table2
     ON table.id = table2.id
WHERE file_id = '5871' AND
      (table1.debit <> 0 OR table1.credit <> 0);
```

Equivalent logic would be:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 INNER JOIN 
     table2
     ON table.id = table2.id
WHERE file_id = '5871' AND
      NOT (table1.debit = 0 AND table1.credit = 0);
```

If you have no `NULL` values, both of these will return the complement of the first query.

Answer (score 3):

On that picture you wont get any data through as the table you have shown wont satisfy BOTH conditions. There isnt a row that has both column 1 not equaling 0 and column 2 not equaling 0, you need to use the operator "or"
Whereas you do have some rows where both columns are 0

Comment: In `mysql` either will work. [see here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html).

Comment: `!=` is a deprecated operator version still supported by many dbms products.

Comment: While it's true that the standard operator is `<>`, most systems also accept `!=` with the same meaning.

Comment: Both operators are valid on mysql

Comment: @jarlh The SQL standard only specifies `<>`, the presence of `!=` is not 'deprecated', it is just 'non-standard', a lot of dialects provide it for convenience.

Comment: #mustbeanoob ignore me!

Comment: I have tried using <> 0  it still returning no results

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, you're probably right. I couldn't find any SQL-89 spec, but it's not in SQL-92 anyway.